# check the particular username already present in SCP

Tags: perl, scp

i want to check if user name is already present in the particular host or not using SCP. how can i do that?

Comment: present in SCP? What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Have you looked at [`finger(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finger)?

Comment: `scp` is a secure copy program.  It is used to transfer files between hosts, not look up users.

Comment: suppose i am login with username called user1 and if the user1 is not there but the host is asking password if the user name is not already present .. so i need to check the username is already present or not in a particular host ..

Comment: Like @JonathanAllard said, but it may not be available since it's a [gaping security hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_protocol#Security_concerns). On a related note, I sure hope that what you're asking isn't possible.

Comment: i think it may be possible as jonathan Allard said .. finger may be useful for me .. thank u Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

(Transporting the answer from the comments to an actual answer, for the purpose of future visitors,)

You may have some success with [`finger(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finger).

But as @tjameson said in the comments, "it may not be available since it's a [gaping security hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_protocol#Security_concerns)."

You might want to reevaluate what functionality you're trying to achieve.

Comment: finger(1) is working within the same host .. not working with remote host i think

Comment: actually if i enter scp user1@host and it asking password recursively if the user1 is not in the particular host .. thats my problem ..

Comment: Indeed, and that's for security reasons. That's why pretty much only `finger` could tell you that.